# PHP Array values - I need to know if they are definitely empty

Tags: php, arrays, function, comparison, for-loop

Here is my example array $postcodeSuppliers:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AB123
    [postcode] => AB123
    [1] => TEST
    [supplier_1] => TEST
    [2] =>  
    [supplier_2] =>  
    [3] =>  
    [supplier_3] =>  
)
```

I have been trying to confirm whether a supplier is empty.
Here is the code I have been using for this:

```
function generateQuoteSuppliers($postcodeSuppliers) {

    $quoteSupplier = array("supplier_1", "supplier_2", "supplier_3");
    //print("<pre>");
    //print_r($postcodeSuppliers);
    //print("</pre>");

    for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $supplier = $postcodeSuppliers['supplier_' . $i . ''];
        //if ($supplier == '')
        //if (!isset($supplier))
        if (empty($supplier)) {
            //A fake supplier is added here 'FAKE' if any of the 3 suppliers contain no date
            echo "NO SUPPLIER";
            $quoteSupplier['supplier_' . $i . ''] = array
                (
                'supplier' => 'FAKE',
                'price' => 0
            );
        } else {
            $quoteSupplier['supplier_' . $i . ''] = array
                (
                'supplier' => $postcodeSuppliers['supplier_' . $i . ''],
                'price' => 0
            );
        }
    }

    return $quoteSupplier;
}
```

None of the methods I have been using to check if the value is empty are working. I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => supplier_1
    [1] => supplier_2
    [2] => supplier_3
    [supplier_1] => Array
        (
            [supplier] => TEST
            [price] => 0
        )

    [supplier_2] => Array
        (
            [supplier] =>  
            [price] => 0
        )

    [supplier_3] => Array
        (
            [supplier] =>  
            [price] => 0
        )

)
```

When I am expecting this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => supplier_1
    [1] => supplier_2
    [2] => supplier_3
    [supplier_1] => Array
        (
            [supplier] => TEST
            [price] => 0
        )

    [supplier_2] => Array
        (
            [supplier] => FAKE
            [price] => 0
        )

    [supplier_3] => Array
        (
            [supplier] => FAKE 
            [price] => 0
        )

)
```

Can someone show me where I am going wrong please? I am completely open to the fact I am wrong! or using my array incorrectly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by empty? Empty string?

Comment: Where is the data coming from in the first place? Are you sure that the "empty" supplier isn't being assigned a space or something like that? You might also be able to test against `NULL` or `""` i.e. `if($supplier == NULL)`

Comment: The initial data comes from a MySQL table. German Rumm's answer is correct. For some reason (which I will look into) the 'empty' suppliers in the first array must contain some white space. A lesson definitely learned. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `trim()` before passing `$supplier` to `empty()`

Comment: Thank you. You pointed out my mistake by assuming the original data was indeed empty.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the language constructor `isset()`

Comment: Agreed, using empty() on a non-existent array key will throw a notice and can cause difficult-to-trace bugs.